# how do i adjust the object to fit the box, kind of like wrapping it just like clothing simulation

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

i'm trying to figure out how to wrap the vest around the block, so the straps that were meant for a human torso would fit the block

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to simulate this because your vest is too complex for it to work properly. I think that only thing you can do is change either block or change the vest manually by lattice, sculpting (grab) or proportional editing

Comment: provide your blend file so we can try ourselves...